# How to define different criteria for FIND and ORDER in std::set

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Client {
   string client_id;
   int    salary;   

   // allow client to sorted by salary
   bool operator<(const Client& rhs) const {
      return salary < rhs.salary;
   }

   // expect to search on client_id but this doesn't work
   bool operator==(const Client& rhs) const {
      return client_id == rhs.client_id;
   }
};    

int main()
{
   set<Client> clients;

   clients.emplace(Client{"a001", 10});
   clients.emplace(Client{"a002", 20});

   if (clients.find(Client{"a0001", 10}) != clients.end()) // Found
     cout << "Found\n";
   else
     cout << "Not Found\n";

   if (clients.find(Client{"a0002"}) != clients.end()) // Not Found
     cout << "Found\n";
   else
     cout << "Not Found\n";     
   return 0;
}
```

The output result of `set::find` does match [this document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/).
The `set::find` is based on the the container's comparison object which is in turn based on the `salary` rather than `client_id`.

Question> In this case, I need to order `Clients` based on their `salary` but when in search I would like to search based on `client_id`. Is there a way to work around this? I would like to use STL functions rather than write a loop myself.

Comment: Your `<` operation semantics should not contradict the semantics of `==`. Did you think about keeping a `set` sorted by salary, and additionally a [multi]map clientid -> client[s]?

Comment: I expect someone to point me to the correct design philosophy

Comment: Very simple: define operations you need, check how often they are going to be called, select the most appropriate data structure. If you need fast adding and list ordered by X, and fast lookup by Y, so be it: you need sorted list by X and a lookup (i.e., map) by Y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard algorithm std::find

if ( find( clients.begin(), clients.end(), Client{"a0001", 10} ) ) != clients.end()) // Found
     cout << "Found\n";